# Display none not working

Tags: javascript, css

I am tryinng to do this:

If my shopping cart is empty then another div shows over the top of it. So you dont see the cart but see a div saying 'your cart is empty'

I have the other div set as display:none in my css, but its always displayed! im trying to use javascript to hide or show it. the cart im using is simplecart js.

heres my css for the cart and the cart-empty div

```
.cart{
margin: 30px 0 0 0;
background:red;
position:relative;
}
#if-cart-empty{
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
display: none;
background:w
```

this is the html

```
<div class="cart">',
<div class="simpleCart_items"></div>',
<span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> items - <span class="simpleCart_total"></span>',
<div class="checkout">',
<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout</a>',
</div>',
<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_empty">Empty Basket</a>',
<div id="if-cart-empty" style="display: none">Your cart is empty.</div>',
</div>',
```

and this is the js

```
checkCart();
$('.itemremove').click(function(){    
$('.itemContainer').remove();  
checkCart();
});

function checkCart(){
var item = $('.itemRow');
if (item.length > 0) {
$('#if-cart-empty').hide();
} else {
$('#if-cart-empty').show();
}
}
```

Can anyone help me get this to work?
Thanks

Comment: What have you learned from checking the style via the browser developer tools?

Comment: is it not working or is the div appearing underneith?

Comment: The problem is that youre calling checkCart on load. Which im sure is fine but Its getting item.legnth to be greater than 0. That is where your problem lies. Console.log the length and see what it is. I think youll need a new way of checking if there are items

Comment: Where is .itemRow .itemRemove and .itemContainer?

Comment: Just make a Fiddle a problem like this is almost imposible to resolve only seeing the code

Comment: Why there is a comma after every HTML Tag? and what is background:w in #if-cart-empty and why its not closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in this case, what happens is, when you declare `display: none;` in the CSS rules, and then use jQuery to `.hide()` or `.show()` the `<div>`, it doesn't work in the first attempt. My advice is you can use it in two ways:

1. By defining a class `class="hide"` and then toggling the class. i.e., `.toggleClass("hide")`.
2. By hiding the `div` using `.hide()` method on `$(document).ready();`.

This is a bug / feature of jQuery / JavaScript. So this is the best way to deal it. If there's no `display: none` in the `style` attribute of a element, jQuery simply treats it as visible. I can show you a fiddle demonstrating it.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/r8y6E/